# find holidays between start Date and End Date from list of Holidays

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a method which returning list of Holidays between StartDate and End Date.I am adding Holidays in database so suppose that there is holiday in database like 14/01/2014-16/01/2014.
So If I am searching holidays from 15/01/2014 it is working fine but If I am searching from 15-17 it gives Exception Like IndexOutOfBoundException

```
public List<HolidayDTO> getHolidayBetweenDate(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    Session session = null;
    List<HolidayDTO> holidayDtoList = null;
    try {
        session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Holiday.class);
        List<Holiday> holidayList = criteria.add(
                Restrictions
                .between("holidayStartDate", startDate, endDate))
                .list();

        if (holidayList != null && holidayList.size() > 0) {
            holidayDtoList = new ArrayList<HolidayDTO>();
            Iterator<Holiday> holidayIterator = holidayList.iterator();
            while (holidayIterator.hasNext()) {
                Holiday holiday = holidayIterator.next();
                HolidayDTO holidayDto = new HolidayDTO();
                holidayDto.setHolidayId(holiday.getHolidayId());
                holidayDto.setHolidayName(holiday.
                        getHolidayName());
                holidayDto.setHolidayDuration(holiday. getHolidayDuration());
                holidayDto.setHolidayStartDate(holiday
                        .getHolidayStartDate());
                holidayDto.setHolidayEndDate(holiday.
                        getHolidayEndDate());
                StateDTO stateDto = new StateDTO();
                stateDto.setStateId(holiday.getState().
                        getStateId());
                stateDto.setStateName(holiday.getState()  .getStateName());
                CountryDTO countryDto = new CountryDTO();
                countryDto.setId(holiday.getState().
                        getCountry().getId());
                countryDto.setCountryCode(holiday.getState().
                        getCountry()
                        .getCountryCode());
                countryDto.setCountryName(holiday.getState().
                        getCountry()
                        .getCountryName());
                stateDto.setCountry(countryDto);
                holidayDto.setState(stateDto);
                holidayDtoList.add(holidayDto);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return holidayDtoList;
}
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace as it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same situation few days back. I think its related to time stamp issue.

I have followed alternative approach for the same "<>" old school solution.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("holidayStartDate", startDate)); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("holidayStartDate", endDate));
```